# Google sheet formula: TRUE if column B is duplicate in either column A or column B

Tags: google-sheets

I have two columns, Name 1 and Name 2. I need an ARRAYFORMULA formula that tells me whether Name 2 appears elsewhere in either Name 1 or Name 2.

| Name 1 | Name 2 | Is Name2 duplicate (formula) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Sam | Jay |  |
| Sandra | Judy | Yes |
| Jane | Judy | Yes |
| Pete | Sam | Yes |
| Pete | Sarah |  |
| Gerry | Gerry | Yes |

It needs to be an arrayformula so it gets added automatically to any new rows.

I can compare either column to a single column:

```
={"match name 1";ARRAYFORMULA(if(COUNTIF (A:A, B2:B)>0, "yes",""))}
={"match name 2";ARRAYFORMULA(if(COUNTIF (B:B, B2:B)>1, "yes",""))}
```

I can also make a non-arrayformula formula that compares to both columns:

```
=OR(COUNTIF (A:A, B2:B)>0,COUNTIF (B:B, B2:B)>1)
```

However, I can't seem to get the OR() and COUNTIF to work with ARRAYFORMULA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Modifying your suggested formula to be:*

```js
={"match name 2";arrayformula(if(len(B2:B),if(countif(A:B,B2:B)>1,"Yes",""),))}
```

***Alternative***:

```js
=map(B2:B,lambda(Σ,if(Σ="",,if(countif(A:B,Σ)>1,"Yes",))))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I used the first formula. Didn't test the second.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **`+`** operator instead of the **`OR`** function:

```cpp
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF((COUNTIF(A2:A,B2:B)>0)+(COUNTIF(B2:B,B2:B)>1),"Yes",))
```

[image]